# Mac OS Sierra 10.12.1 Mouse click (double click and triple click)

Tags: macos, macos-sierra

### Problem statement:

I just updated to macOS Sierra 10.12.1 (from OS X Yosemite) but now note that double click will select all text on the line.  Before this update double click selected the word or IP that I was over and triple click selected the entire line.

### Problem TL;DR

Before update:

- double-click = selected word
- triple-click = selected entire line

After update:

- double-click = selects entire line

### EDIT:

**So I just noted that this is only in web brousers (Tested in Safari and Google Chrome) text editors like Caret (Google Chrome app/extension) are unaffected**.

### EDIT 2:

- Attempted Shutdown without re-opening apps to no avail.
- Also noted that double clicking in Microsoft apps seems to be proving problematic like launcing a RDP session in Microsoft Remote Desktop or selecting a blank document in Microsoft Word.

### EDIT 3:

See below answer if you have a Razer Naga. I have to wait 48 hours before resolving. 
[image]

### Attempted resolution:

I have been all over System Preference but have not found anything yet.  I also googled this a bit but it doesn't appear that people are talking about this yet (I note that this version was released 4 days ago).

[image]

Visited Articles for Sierra:

https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25809?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US
https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25268?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

### Why this is important to me:

This might seem trivial but this is going to seriously slow down my workflow since I have to select VM names and IP's from sentences for a good portion of my day.

### Questions:

- Has anyone else expirienced this?
- Does anyone have a solution? (Looking to resolve without third part products).

### Version:

10.12.1 (16B2657)

[image]

**Thanks in advance for any help.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is somewhat embarrassing and unexpected.  This issue stemmed from my Razer Naga 2014's software.  I was promoted with an update shortly after upgrading to Sierra.

[image]

I installed this update and everything is peachy now.

I realize that I should probably brought this up earlier in my problem statement.

Thanks for reading! I hope this helps someone else.

### EDIT:

I guess I have to wait 2 days before resolving.

[image]

Comment: Hey Robert, I have the same issue with a Razer Orochi (bluetooth mouse). The issue is only presenting when using it via bluetooth, with the cable everything is fine. I have installed the latest version of Synapse. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @EdoB I am actually still plagued with this.  I have found hitting the escape key a couple times (2-3) will clear this errored state.  I think that this is an error with the `Razer`Software.  I personally have been plagued with bugs, and have stopped updating the software once I got to a relatively good release.  It would seem that there is quite a bit of instability with their software releases, at least from my perspective.  I run into this a lot when transferring from an RDP session to my normal macOS desktop or when first connecting my thunderbolt display (where my mouse is plugged in).

Comment: @EdoB Thinking about this further I decided to backup my `Razer` Software before updating.  This can be done via: `tar -zcvf ~/Documents/Razr.tar.gz /Applications/Razer\ Synapse.app/ ` If there is an undesired bug with the update you would then be able to `rm -rf /Applications/Razer\ Synapse.app/ && tar -zxvf ~/Documents/Razr.tar.gz --directory /Applications/`